# How are fingerings on ornamented notes to be interpreted?

Tags: piano, fingering, ornaments

Do fingerings refer to the "main" note or the first note of the ornament realization?

Suppose I have a trilled B over which the editor has put a 3.

Does it mean that I play it 3-2, the C with the 3 and the B with the 2 (or 1), or does it mean that I play the B with the 3 and the C with whatever I want - 4 or 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually that would mean the main note, unless the editor actually writes out the ornamentation and puts the fingerings on that.

It's also important to try and figure out the logic behing the fingering by looking at the context – what happens before, and what happens after.